# intent not getting passed via OnClickListener

Tags: android

Problem:
I would like my Intent to take me to new activity but showing me Constructor error.

```
package com.example.vidit.books;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final EditText query = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.query);
    Button submit= (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);

            submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    Intent intent= new Intent(MainActivity.class,Request.class);
                    intent.putExtra ( "text", query.getText().toString() );
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
            });
}
}
```

The Intent where transition happens is Underlined in Red.
Request for help

Comment: "Underlined in Red" is not any error. What does it say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line :

```
                Intent intent= new Intent(MainActivity.class,Request.class);
                intent.putExtra ( "text", query.getText().toString() );
                startActivity(intent);
```

to this :

```
                Intent intent= new Intent(MainActivity.this,Request.class);
                intent.putExtra ( "text", query.getText().toString() );
                startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass first parameter as context, like this :

```
Intent intent= new Intent(MainActivity.this,Request.class);
intent.putExtra ( "text", query.getText().toString() );
startActivity(intent);
```

Reference link : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#Intent(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.Class%3C?%3E)

```
Intent (Context packageContext, Class<?> cls)
```

Comment: Context is represented by `this` keyword and not `java`

Comment: yeah, sorry my mistake. I did it accidentally.

Answer (score 0):

> **Use this**

```
Intent intent= new Intent(MainActivity.this,Request.class);
```

> **Instead of this**

```
Intent intent= new Intent(MainActivity.class,Request.class);
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this

Intent intent= new Intent(this,Request.class);